# Redirect to frontend in directory or API in another directory using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directive

I have the following directory structure where `/root` acts as my root directory despite being nested among any number of subdirectories:

- example.com/dir1/root

  - client/build
  - api

When the user navigates to `example.com/dir1/root/`, I'd like all requests to be redirected to `example.com/dir1/root/client/build/` but **without changing the URL**, as if the `build/` directory contents were inside `root/`.

Additionally, I'd like all requests like `example.com/dir1/root/api/*` to be redirected to `example.com/dir1/root/api/`. Again, without changing the URL.

This is my current attempt, given my little understanding of how .htaccess works:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Redirect all requests under /api/ to the API.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/
RewriteRule ^ api/index.php [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html (html5mode)
RewriteRule ^ client/build/index.html [L]
```

Note: I've searched but not found any answers for this specific scenario, and given my poor htaccess knowledge, I'm unable to cobble existing answers together very well.

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located? Are you OK with having multiple `.htaccess` files (since you are seemingly performing different/unrelated tasks)? "to be redirected to `example.com/dir1/root/client/build/`" - your code is rewriting to `index.html`? "to be redirected to `example.com/dir1/dir/2/api/`" - again, your code is redirecting to `index.php` - please clarify.

Comment: @MrWhite yes that's correct, `index.php` and `index.html`. Also, multiple `.htaccess` files is fine. The existing `.htaccess` is located in `dir1/root/`. Also note that index.php must retain query parameters such as `example.com/dir1/root/api/items?limit=4`. There's also various assets inside `client/build` that are referenced by `index.html` as though they are in `root/`

Comment: Just a further clarification... in your question you refer to `example.com/dir1/dir/2/api/` - however, that does not appear to follow the stated directory structure ie. `/dir1/root/api` (which you've also referenced in your comment)?

Comment: @MrWhite sorry that was a mistake, I've edited the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `index.html` is requesting resources like `example.com/dir1/root/assets/style.css` when this resides in `/root/client/build/assets/`. Essentially, I want `/root/` to behave as if it's actually `/root/client/build`, except in the instance `/root/api/` is requested.

I would implement this as 2 separate `.htaccess` files. One in the "root" directory (ie. `/dir1/root/.htaccess`) that handles the "api" requests and rewrites everything else to `client/build` (ie. a "false root"). And another `.htaccess` file in `/dir1/root/client/build/.htaccess` that handles just the routing within your app frontend.

For example:

```
# /dir1/root/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite all requests under /api/ to the API handler "index.php"
RewriteRule ^api/(?!index\.php) api/index.php [L]

# Rewrite everything else to the "client/build/" subdirectory
RewriteRule (.*) client/build/$1 [L]
```

And...

```
# /dir1/root/client/build/.htaccess

DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On

# Front-controller
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

The presence of the `.htaccess` file (containing mod_rewrite directives) in the subdirectory also serves to prevent a rewrite-loop, since it prevents directives in the parent `.htaccess` being re-processed (and rewriting the request back to `client/build/...` again and again).

---

A quick look at your existing rules...

> ```
> # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is.
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
> RewriteRule ^ - [L]
>
> # Redirect all requests under /api/ to the API.
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/
> RewriteRule ^ api/index.php [L]
>
> # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html (html5mode)
> RewriteRule ^ client/build/index.html [L]
> ```

Issues with your existing rules:

- Since the first rule prevents any requests that map to files or directories being processed, it will also prevent requests for `/dir1/root/` itself (which is a directory) being rewritten to `/dir1/root/client/build/index.html`.
- The *condition* `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/` will never be successful since the `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the root-relative URL-path, ie. `/dir1/root/api/`.
- Since everything else is rewritten from the "root" to `client/build/index.html`, the static assets that also reside in `client/build/` are not rewritten correctly (they are rewritten to `index.html` so presumably result in an unexpected response).
- You can't perform the filesystem checks in the "root" `.htaccess` file, since the static assets that relate to `index.html` only "exist" after they have been rewritten.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. However, would it be possible to reroute requests from the client as well? For example, `index.html` is requesting resources like `example.com/dir1/root/assets/style.css` (resulting in 404) when this resides in `/root/client/build/assets/`. Essentially, I want `/root/` to behave as if it's actually `/root/client/build`, except in the instance `/root/api/` is requested.

Comment: @Matt Ah yes, sorry I missed that. I've updated/rewritten my answer.